# How do/did you detect plagiarism?

Tags: discussion

I was browsing [a question thrown up by Mr. Community](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/5022/not-in-sync-resp-0x00) when I noticed that one of the replies had been deleted by a moderator for plagiarism.

I'm impressed that it was noticed, but how was that done? Did the moderator just have a really good memory? Or was it reported by someone else with a good memory? Or are there some automated ways of detecting plagiarism?

Answer (score 2):

It was reported by someone else with a good memory. Plagiarism is generally considered rude, and folks are encouraged to report it when they see it; there's even a handy [help-center page](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) to refer folks to if they seem to be having trouble referencing others' work in a respectful manner.

Answer (score 0):

Actually both assumptions are correct.  Check with your local high school they may have the software that does this.  It could also be our moderator, the more you read the more you will recognize.

Answer (score 0):

If I see a rather (suspiciously) well written answer, from someone with a low reputation, I generally copy an eight to ten word chunk of it which contains specific text not likely to be found in general text or conversation and google it. It will normally come back in the top of the search results as someone else's work.

Tedious? Yes, and it may seem to be a bit anally retentive but it seems to work. Maybe I am just a suspicious paranoid type...
:-)